# Show Last 5 ratings using DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

Helo everyone,

I want to show a table with last 5 customer ratings using a dax measure.

Link to the excel file is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7_b-JCiqPuTMGCcfNWkW8UlFZDOvnvR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104391721984097092775&rtpof=true&sd=true

Thanks
Here is the table how should it be displayed. I have found multiple articles but most of them are related to finding total sales or some kind of aggregates. Purpose is to find the last 5 ratings by each customer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You need a measure to achieve it, not a table:

Let's create a measure first:

```
Top5_Rating =
VAR Picking =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Ratings[Customer] )
VAR AddRank =
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE ( Ratings, Ratings[Customer] = Picking ),
            "Rank", RANKX ( Ratings, Ratings[Satisfaction Date],, DESC, DENSE )
        ),
        [Rank] <= 5
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( AddRank, [Satisfaction-rating] )
```

Then create a table visual, and put satisfaction date on rows, and above measure next to it: Also construct a slicer by using customer column. Then It gives us:

[image: TAble lldkdkka]

You need one more step to do:

With your table visual selected, on the filter pane:

Make the related changes, see the picture below:

[image: DERS]

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works but when I try to apply a month slicer, let's say october 2022 is selected it does not show anything. It works only when all of the values in the month slicer are selected (all months of 2022 in this case)  Here is the screenshot
https://snipboard.io/DCLfM7.jpg

Comment: Where do you get the slicer month value? Please create 'date' dimension table, and then bind it to your fact table by (0ne_To_Many relationship) then you can filter by any feature(month, day, period, quarter) This is the best method. If you want to do it on a measure, define another VAR parameter = SELECTEDVALUE (SlicerTableName[SlicerTableColumnName]) then put it into the 2nd filter parameter of CALCULATETABLE() inside the measure.